# Is there a pure java library for converting DXF to PNG?

Tags: java, png, dxf

Need to convert DXF files to PNG. Found a library called kabeja --  http://kabeja.sourceforge.net/

The conversion however is limited. It does not work with fill patterns. Any better tools?

Comment: hay did you find any solution about above problem? I'm also trying to find a way to get snap shot from DXF file. Can you share your experience with me

Comment: @SL_User: The library below had same problem as that kabeja. I used kabeja and stopped at what it could not provide.

Comment: have u taken a image from the DXF file?? Please can you share that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this java app: http://www.escape.de/~quincunx/dxfviewer/

You could mail the guy asking for the source and modify it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I will mail the owner. (added a link to this  in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD_DXF)